# Download a file from the internet?

Tags: c#, download

How can I easily download a file from internet in C#?

Thank you very much.

Comment: you should really edit your question to be a more clear about what your after and why.  as is, its too generic to provide much more than the most general of responses.  what have you tried so far?  what errors have occurred? etc.

Answer (score 8):

[WebClient.DownloadFIle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx) is one simple way.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the BCL class [`System.Net.WebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28VS.71%29.aspx). Here's a brief example:

```
using System.Net;
...

var request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://..."));
var response = request.GetResponse();
var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//  read web resource content through this stream object!
...
```

Take note:

- Some of these objects are `IDisposable`, so in real code you might want to wrap them in `using` blocks.
- The above code example does not do any error checking. You might want to add appropriate code for this, also.